# Python3: Compartmentalized large class by programmatically adding functions from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, python-importlib

**Note**: This question is a modification / extension of [Adding functions from other files to a Python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865455/adding-functions-from-other-files-to-a-python-class). This is partially because `imp` is deprecated.

**Context**: I have a large class file (+5000 lines), say `MainClass.py`. To better compartmentalize my code, I would like to move related functions into separate subfiles e.g. the desired directory structure might resemble:

```
- my_package 
|
| - .__init__.py
| - MainClass.py
|
| - main_class_functions
| |  - .__init__.py
| |  - function_group_1.py
| |  - function_group_2.py
| |  ...
```

I would like to be able to load these functions and add them to the `MainClass`

Currently I have:

```
# MainClass.py
import os
import importlib

class MainClass(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._compartmentalized_functions_directory = 'main_class_functions'
    self._location = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

  def load_functions(self):
    # absolute path to directory of where the function files are located
    function_files_directory = os.path.join(self.location, self._compartmentalized_functions_directory)

    #
    [importlib.import_module(file, os.path.join(function_files_directory, file)) for file in os.listdir(function_files_directory)]



# main_class_functions_1.py
def test(self):
  print("test")
```

But this spits an `ImportError`, `'main_class_functions_1' is not a package`.

(I have also copy-pasted the code from the linked post and tried to see if that worked, but it did not).

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but thinking out of the box: Instead of monkey-patch-assembling your class it might be a cleaner solution to create smaller classes (mixins) in multiple files and compose them to the ultimate huge class using multiple inheritance.

Comment: @kazemakase could you make a small example?

Comment: I don't have the time, sorry. See if [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/multiple-inheritance) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python) can get you started.